# Are directories handled by Hadoop cache symlinks?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I am trying to figure out if symlinks created by the Hadoop cache support directories .

- It works well in distributed mode
- It fails in local mode
- Javadoc / documentation is very sparse and say nothing about it

## Short version

I expect `DistributedCache.addCacheFile(URI.create("file:/tmp/myfile#foo/bar"), conf)` to make `/tmp/myfile` available in the current working directory under the name `foo/bar`.

Everything is fine on the cluster, but it fails in local mode.  Basically, `LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup` tries to create the symlink using `ln -s /tmp/myfile $cwd/foo/bar` but `foo` has never being created.

## Detailed requirements

I want to add one or several Avro [SortedKeyValueFile](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/hadoop/file/SortedKeyValueFile.html) to the Hadoop distributed cache.

`SortedKeyValueFile`s are similar to Hadoop `MapFile`s. They are in fact a directory made of two files: an index file and a data file. These two files must have a specific name (`index` and `data`) and must be in the same directory.

If I want to be able to put at least two of theses "file" in the distributed cache, I cannot flatten the files into the root directory. I have to preserve / define a file hierarchy.

Setup: Hadoop 2.6.0 / CDH 5.4 / Crunch. Because I am using Crunch, I have to use the deprecated `DistributedCache` API since `Job.addCachefile()` is not exposed.

## Questions to be answered

- Is it a bug in the local mode or am I abusing the distributed cache ?
- How do people push things like `MapFile` or `SortedKeyValueFile` into the Hadoop cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bug in the local mode or am I abusing the distributed cache ?

> Distributedcache is not supported in local mode. It will run only in pseudo-distributed mode or in cluster mode.

How do people push things like MapFile or SortedKeyValueFile into the Hadoop cache ?

> You have to put everything in the file and place it in HDFS and in
>   mapside read it from the file and put it in hashmap.

How to read from a distributed cache:

```
@Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
        {
            Path[] filelist=DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
            for(Path findlist:filelist)
            {
                if(findlist.getName().toString().trim().equals("mapmainfile.dat"))
                {

                    fetchvalue(findlist,context);
                }
            }

        }
        public void fetchvalue(Path realfile,Context context) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
        {
            BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(realfile.toString()));
           //read the file and put it in hashMap
        }
```

Adding a file to distributed cache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hduser/test/mapmainfile.dat"),conf);
```

Comment: 1- You can put a breakpoint in `LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup()` to see that the distributed cache is configured even in local mode (perhaps it is a Pig limitation ?). 2- SortedKeyValueFile are used purposely, using an  in memory collection in not an option. I can definitively copy the two files on the local filesystem by myself at the beginning of each attempt. But it defeats the effectiveness of the distributed cache and would require extra  code to cleanup the mess in local mess .

Comment: It has no way to handle this rather than saying it as a limitation.When we run the job in local mode it doesn't create any local data directory, hence no place for cache files. This is what the document(https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata) says 'As a cautionary note: If you use the local JobRunner in Hadoop (i.e., what happens if you call JobClient.runJob() in a program with no or an empty hadoop-conf.xml accessible), then no local data directory is created; the getLocalCacheFiles() call will return an empty set of results.'

Comment: Indeed, an attempt dir is not created in local mode. However, the distributed cache supports symlinks since a while (had to be enabled on MR1, on by default on MR2). A symlink is created in the current directory for each file.  By default, its has the same name that the source file; but adding a fragment to the URI allows you to change it (and AFAIU its *relative path* too). In local mode, CWD is where you launched the JVM and http://bit.ly/1NnyyHc creates the symlinks. However "#/foo/name" is supported by distributed mode but not local mode (would require some mkdir before the ln).